# Compact convex body

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $L$ and $K$ be two compact convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  suppose $L$  is proper subset of $K$ and $0 \in \operatorname{(L)} $. Prove that there exists a point $p\in \operatorname{int}(K)-L$.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This does not look correct.  What if $K$ has no interior? Such as a 1-dimensional line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$:  $$K = \{(x,0)  : 0\leq x \leq 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$$

Comment: @Michael That could be fixed by assuming that $K$ is affine spanning, or equivalently assuming that we mean the interior of $K$ as a subspace of its affine span. Nonetheless, hopefully the OP will clarify.

Comment: Additionally, @JuanCarlosQuesadaVargas, you'll get better responses on this site if you explain where exactly you're getting stuck with the question, and if you can't start the question, which words you don't understand and why you're having trouble getting started.

Comment: @jgon :  I think another word for that is "relative interior."

Comment: @Michael so it is :) Thanks, I didn't know there was a word for that.